# Current with an ionic solution

Tags: electrochemistry

For the last assignment of the school year, my science teacher gave the class questions about chem, physics, etc. The third question had me confused and I'll be thankful for all the help given. The question is:

> An ionic solution is created and tested to see how much current can go
> through it. Two groups are told to create the following solution
> consisting of $\pu{1.0 +/- 0.1 L}$ of water and $\pu{2.0 +/- 0.2 g}$ [of what?] . The battery used for the test is $\ce{8 +/- 1 V}$.
>
> Group A measures a current of $\pu{2.1 +/-0.1 mA}$.  Group
> B measures a current of $\pu{3.4 +/- 0.1 mA}$.
>
> Describe 3 possible reasons why Group B measures a current greater
> than group A.

Comment: (The "water" after the 2g was not in the question originally.)

Comment: Why are the error margins explicitly mentioned? Aren't they supposed to be implicit?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb What is an "implicit" error margin?

Comment: The last digit in any measurement is doubtful, so $1.0 L \equiv 1.0 \pm 0.1 L$. My terminology might be a bit incorrect here, so feel free to correct me.

Comment: @Aniruddha Deb Hmm, 1.0 without explicit margins may as well be 1.00 +- 0.05, with errors rounding to 1.0. so 1.0 +- 0.1 is more particular than just 1.0.

Comment: @Poutnik you  mean "specific", i guess ;)

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb You need to differentiate between +- giving a *standard deviation* (in which case you might be able to give two significant figures), and a simple assumed measurement error margin.

Answer (score 4):

No offence to you (certainly to the original author of this question), I call such home-work questions such as garbage in-garbage out type questions. No wonder a student will be confused if they see such open ended questions. The reason is that the author is not telling you or us of 2.0 grams of what?

Even if we assume it was 2 grams of salt, several things can affect the measured current

(1) What are the electrode areas?
(2) What are the electrodes made of?
(3) What is the distance between the electrodes?

Last but not the least, the identity of the salt matters a lot. Did both groups use the same salt? Monovalent, divalent, etc

Answer (score 4):

This question (the one by your teacher, not yours) becomes ridiculous if we do not take a few things for granted:

- same (unidentified) salt
- water from the same tap
- identical set of electrodes
- identical, clean beakers (or at least they were together in the same washing machine).
- identical distance and position of electrodes
- same temperature

because the influence of either of them is either arbitrary (*distance*!) or very hard to ascertain for a high school student (electrode material), or anybody who is given so little information.

Now you can check if the uncertainties given in the text are enough to explain the difference. At 8 V, everything should be linear enough, and yes, it seems that together, the errors could explain the difference.

What the *other* two explanations could be, I have no idea. Your teacher should probably be ashamed of himself for insulting the students with such a badly devised question. Unless we are grossly misinterpreting his aim and attempt. ;-)

Comment: Well ... to be generous, one could think that the teacher is attempting to teach the lesson that all of those things matter, and that if reproduction of an experiment fails, you should consider every possible difference! So the "badly devised" question is designed to make students think outside the box. Possible?

Comment: @RossPresser You´re right, *in dubio pro reo!* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The question formulation may look strange, but still makes sanse, whatever salt is used.

The difference of results is at the edge to be cause just due uncertainties of volume, mass or voltage, or by (usual ) used electrode material.

I see 3 other potential sources of the difference, as it is unclear if the experiment settings is otherwise identical or not:

1. Higher electrode surface leads to higher current at the same voltage, as the current density would be about the same.
2. Shorter electrode distance leads to higher current due higher volatge gradient.
3. Mixing electrolyte leads to higher current, as it cancels the diffusion limitation.